# Meteor 0.9.3.1: node modules not being installed from packages.json

Tags: meteor

I've installed a fresh copy of Meteor and my application.  I am now running version `Meteor 0.9.3.1`.

I expected the nodejs modules to install when I started my app but nothing appeared to happen.  As a result when trying to invoke methods that use these node modules:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'npmRequire'
```

For example the graphics lib is being invoked like so:

```
var gm = Meteor.npmRequire('gm');
```

I also have the `meteorhacks:npm` module installed.

I can't see anything I'm doing wrong.  Here's my packages.json file:

```
{
"gm"      :"1.16.0",
"mkdirp"  :"0.5.0"
}
```

Anyone got any idea on this?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like `meteorhacks:npm` is not loaded, are you sure it is included in the `.meteor/packages` file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem was, but I did a fresh install and installed `meteorhacks:npm` first then ran my app.  The node modules installed at that point.  All working now :)